# Add VBox multiple times to listView

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder, vbox

I have a VBox that I created through Scene Builder and inside it, there is a Button, textField, and a Combobox.I placed the VBox inside a listView. I would like to click an add button and another VBox appears at the bottom of the first one. Such that a user can enter more data as they please.

Thus far in my code, the VBox moves a step down in the listView when I click the add button. I am still new to java so I am not really sure what is missing in the code such that it works as expected.

I have tried to pass to either create a new VBox and add children to it whenever a user clicks the add button but this throws an**java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4**

**This is the code when i used try to add the VBox i created through scene builder:**

```
private ObservableList<VBox> box = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  visibleList.setItems(box);  
  stack1.getChildren().add(visibleList);

}  

@FXML
void addButton() {

   box.add(vbox1);
}
```

**This is the code when I try to create a new vbox and add children to it during runtime :**

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private Button add;

@FXML
private TextField textfd;

@FXML
private ListView<VBox> visibleList;

@FXML
private Label defaultlabel;

@FXML
private StackPane stack1;

@FXML
private VBox vbox1;

@FXML
private HBox hbox1;

@FXML
private Button btn1;

@FXML
private TextField txt1;

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> combo1;

@FXML
private TextArea textarea1;

@FXML
private Button another;


private ObservableList<VBox> box = FXCollections.observableArrayList();


@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

  visibleList.setItems(box);  
  stack1.getChildren().add(visibleList);

}  

@FXML
void addButton() {

   VBox vb = new VBox();
   vb.getChildren().addAll(btn1,txt1,combo1);
   box.add(vb);
}
}
```

**Using CustomCells the program crashes with java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException:**
This is my code :

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

@FXML
private Label label;

@FXML
private Button add;

@FXML
private TextField textfd;

@FXML
private ListView<VBox> visibleList;

@FXML
private Label defaultlabel;

@FXML
private StackPane stack1;

@FXML
private VBox vbox1;

@FXML
private HBox hbox1;

@FXML
private Button btn1;

@FXML
private TextField txt1;

@FXML
private ComboBox<String> combo1;

@FXML
private TextArea textarea1;

@FXML
private Button another;



private ObservableList<Car> cars = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
cars.addAll(new Car(CAR_TYPE.CAR1_tetbeeeee), new Car(CAR_TYPE.CAR2_iububdfcxkndns), new Car(CAR_TYPE.CAR3_nkrebsbcnevjds));

ListView<Car> carsListView = new ListView<>();
carsListView.setCellFactory(c -> new CarListCell());
carsListView.setItems(cars);

stack1.getChildren().add(carsListView);

} 

private class CarListCell extends ListCell<Car> {

private HBox content = new HBox();
private VBox content2 = new VBox();
private ChoiceBox<CAR_TYPE> cb = new ChoiceBox<>();
TextField nametextbox = new TextField ();
TextArea  taskinfo  = new TextArea ();
Label taskid = new Label ("Task#");
Label taskstatus = new Label ("Incomplete");
DatePicker FromDatePicker = new DatePicker();
DatePicker ToDatePicker = new DatePicker();
ComboBox teamlead = new ComboBox(cars);
private Button add = new Button("+");
private Button sub = new Button("-");

public CarListCell() {


    taskinfo.setPrefWidth(730.0);
    teamlead.setPrefWidth(150.0);
    FromDatePicker.setPrefWidth(120);
    ToDatePicker.setPrefWidth(120);
    taskinfo.setPrefHeight(100.0);


    cb.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(CAR_TYPE.values()));
    cb.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
    taskinfo.setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);
    taskinfo.setPrefHeight(USE_PREF_SIZE);
    teamlead.setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);
    FromDatePicker.setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);
    ToDatePicker.setMaxWidth(USE_PREF_SIZE);

   // HBox.setHgrow(cb, Priority.ALWAYS);

    content.getChildren().addAll(taskid,taskstatus,nametextbox,FromDatePicker,ToDatePicker, teamlead,sub,add);
    content2.getChildren().addAll(content,taskinfo);
    content.setSpacing(10);
    content2.setSpacing(10);
    setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    setGraphic(content2);
}

@Override
protected void updateItem(Car item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    if (item == null || empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setGraphic(content2);
        //cb.setValue(item.getType());
        add.setOnAction(e -> {
            Car newCar = new Car(cb.getValue());
            cars.add(newCar);
        });
        sub.setOnAction(e -> {
            cars.remove(item);
        });
    }
}

}

private enum CAR_TYPE {
CAR1_tetbeeeee, CAR2_iububdfcxkndns, CAR3_nkrebsbcnevjds;
}

private class Car {

private CAR_TYPE type;

public Car(CAR_TYPE type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public CAR_TYPE getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(CAR_TYPE type) {
    this.type = type;
}
}

}
```

Comment: You need to create a new version of the node AND it's descendants since a node can just be added to a single place in a single scene graph. I recommend reading about `cellFactory`s though and creating a item class...

Comment: I added the code i used